# Understanding EXPLAIN function in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, explain

Trying to understand EXPLAIN function - I have two queries - first query is optimised, that is running 600 ms(I have 100k rows) and second query is running 900 ms
But when I run EXPLAIN ANALYZE - first query, that is running quickly shows me cost - 64296 and second query, that is running slowly shows me cost - 20873
can't understand why faster query has bigger cost, and why longer running query has smaller cost. 
Could someone give me some hint ?

Comment: Probably because the optimizer is confused and chooses the wrong execution plan for the second query.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL `EXPLAIN` is an animal that really has a lot of arms & legs, each of which can cause it to work in a way that isn't easy to understand at first.

To answer your question, I understand that although running the first query Q1 (not its `EXPLAIN`), it runs faster than the second (Q2), but when you do an `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`, Q1 actually has a higher cost.

I could think of two reasons that come to mind at this moment:

- If the Queries are `LIMIT` queries, its possible for Q1 to execute faster and still have higher 'cost', since the PostgreSQL Planner (intentionally) does not plan for a smaller total cost, but a smaller cost of the required result (in this case, a smaller number of rows).
- Another reason could be that caching could be playing havoc with your times. Could you confirm if the observation is persistent with multiple (3+) runs?

Besides these hunches, if you really want to get deep into understanding `EXPLAIN`, recommend you to refer the following articles [here](http://www.dalibo.org/_media/understanding_explain.pdf), [here](https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/optimizer.pdf) and [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/4/45/Explaining_EXPLAIN.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Cost is what planner thinks about how many recourses (I/O and CPU time) it will take to perform the query. It's just an estimation, calculated by a mathematical model.

In your case planner was wrong, it chose suboptimal plan. It happens sometimes.

Why? There could be many reasons. Maybe statistics are inadequate (try to run `analyze` for your tables first of all). Maybe statistics are ok, but planner uses the wrong model (for example, you may have correlated predicates in your query which are known to be problematic). Maybe your query is over several dozens of tables and planner just can't go through all possible plans. And so on.